# Редирект на предыдущую страницу Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой проблемой (Laravel 5.8).
Есть форма комментариев.
Приведу пример (очень кратко, чтобы не захламлять сам вопрос ненужной инфой)

```
@if(!Auth::check()) // если пользователь не аутентифицирован, показываем форму для анонима
```

`@else // показываем форму для залогиненого пользователя`

Вот так, например, мы залогиним какого-нибудь пользователя вручную

```
Route::get('/login', function (){
auth()->login(Corp\User::find(1));
return back(); // и перенаправляем его на предыдущую страницу });
```

Так вот, после редиректа отображается форма комментариев для анонима, но если страницу перезагрузить, то все в порядке.
Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это связанно с того что вы перенаправляете на предыдущую страницу, то есть браузер возвращается назад логин произведен как бы а html код старый. Используйте `return redirect('/');`

Comment: Спасибо большое!